# How to properly transition to a View Controller from app delegate on receiving remote notification?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm presenting a view controller from app delegate file when remote notification is received.

Inside `didReceiveRemoteNotification`:

```
var rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
let shareController : ShareViewController
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
shareController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("shareController") as! ShareViewController

self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
rootViewController!.presentViewController(shareController, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
    shareController.executeSharing()
 })
```

It is working fine when notification is received but when I force terminate the app and then remote notification is received, the app just opens up but it is not transitioning to ShareViewController.

How do I transition it to ShareViewController when remote notification is received, no matter which controller is currently on top?

Answer (score 0):

The `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method is only called when the app is launched (whether it's in the foreground or in the background. When the app is terminated, this method isn't called, and that's why your current implementation doesn't work. In order to support this case, you need to add special treatment to your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method. The notification object, has a `userInfo` property that will include a flag to let you know that the app was launched as a result of a remote notification (and all of the necessary data for that notification).